# Access property of different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `MainView` and a corresponding `MainViewModel`.
Inside the `MainView` I have a `HeaderView` and a corresponding `HeaderViewModel`.
It looks like this:

[image]

Inside the `MainViewModel's` constructor I create a new instance of the `HeaderViewModel` and pass it some parameters like this:

```
HeaderViewModel = new HeaderViewModel(_eventAggregator, "Kundenstamm");
```

As well there is a property of type `Customer` which is bound to all my textboxes:

```
private Customer _customer;
public Customer Customer
{
    get { return _customer; }
    set
    {
        _customer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now my question is, when I press the save button inside the `HeaderViewModel`, I need to access the property `Customer`. How do I achieve that?
The eventAggregator of Prism doesn't make sense in this case in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could imagine a number of ways to make this work but they basically boil down to:

> The "Header" is basically a user control; it doesn't have enough information to perform the "Save" function so that should be delegated to something that does.

This could be done via:

- Events (`OnSaved` in `HeaderViewModel`, `MainViewModel` subscribes
- Delegates (Pass `SaveCallback` to `HeaderViewModel`'s constructor
- Event Arbiter (3'rd class with the `OnSaved` event, header instructs it to fire)
- Probably a bunch of others.

Personally, I would do the first one. The second is OK too; the third only makes since if `MainViewModel` didn't have direct access to the `HeaderViewModel` instance.